# AWS Stripping HTTP Headers?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, http, go, http-headers

I have two AWS servers running.  One is running a service on GO and the other other is running a PHP application.  When I make the call to the service via my local PHP server the results come back as expected. When I move that same PHP code on AWS the service returns without errors but returns an empty object as if it had some of the HTTP header data stripped off by AWS.  AWS is set up to allow all inbound and outbound traffic.  Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have something like CloudFront in place?

Comment: What services are you actually using?  If this is just EC2, no, Amazon doesn't do anything to your traffic.

Comment: As Brad said, EC2 does nothing to modify any traffic; the most it does is block ports at the VNIC using security groups. If you can connect, then that's not the problem. AWS does have various services that can modify headers though - CloudFront, API Gateway, ALB, WAF, probably others. So the full stack is important - but, seeing as this isn't a programming question, you'd be better served asking over on Server Fault.

Comment: It could also be something inside the VM, like if you've got a reverse proxy in front of your app like Nginx. But that's not something AWS is doing, it's something you've configured on the machine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same problem. I have a dotnet core Console App running as a service on ECS-Fargate. The service tries to call a REST endpoint which requires Authorization Token. When the service calls the endpoint with an AuthToken, the response I get is 401 Unauthorized. I copy the AuthToken from CloudWatch Logs and use it in postman and it works fine; I get a 200 OK. If I run the code in debug mode hardcoding the same AuthToken, the code gets a successful response as well (200 OK). It seems as if the Http Header has been stripped off and AuthToken isn't sent when the REST call is made by my service on AWS.

My setup is, a dotnet core console app (C#) running in a Docker Container hosted on aws using Fargate, running a single instance. Since its a console app, i'm not using any ELB. Security Group allows traffic outside due to which I am getting a response back successfully.

Comment: Hi, did you manage to solve this problem ? We're facing the same issue with lambda java runtime. P.